# python bot block access to command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is it possible to block access to commands if they are not member of specific discord server. example:

If bot is installed in multiple server.

So if any member from any server types `?ping` it should work only if he is member of Main server. otherwise bot reply's with a custom message.

```
class NonMember(commands.CommandError):
    def __init__(self, server_id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.server_id = server_id
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def is_member_of(server_id):
    def predicate(ctx):
        server = bot.get_server(server_id)
        if not server:
            raise commands.CommandError("Cannot poll members of server with id {}".format(server_id))
        if bool(server.get_member(ctx.message.author.id)):
            return True
        else:
            raise NonMember
    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, NonMember):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "{} Not an member. ".format(error.user.mention))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@is_member_of("1234")
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Comment: You're raising the error in the wrong place.  You want to raise the error iff the `bool` check fails.  Something like `if bool(...): return True else: raise MemberError(...)`

Comment: You need to change `return bool(...)` to `if bool(...): return True else: raise NonMember(...)`

Comment: Hello Patrick yes everything works fine but I have another question. That custom `on_command_error` not working for DMs. I tried `await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel,` to `await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author,` so is there anything need to change ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a [`commands.check`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) to use [`Server.get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Server.get_member) to try to find the member in the given server.  Something like

```
class NonMember(commands.CommandError):
    def __init__(self, server_id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.server_id = server_id
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, NonMember):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "{} Not an member. ".format(error.user.mention))

def is_member_of(server_id):
    def predicate(ctx):
        server = bot.get_server(server_id)
        if not server:
            raise commands.CommandError("Cannot poll members of server with id {}".format(server_id))
        if bool(server.get_member(ctx.message.author.id)):
            return True
        else:
            raise NonMember(server_id)
    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@is_member_of("1234")
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Comment: were to enter main server id. `@is_member_of(7687878788)` here ?

Comment: Yes, though it should be a string if you're using the async branch.

Comment: @Demotry `CommandError` is from the `commands` extension.  I'll edit that in my answer

Comment: Got another error for both member and non member of server ID. error code updated above. that id i replaced with fake Id here.

Comment: [`Client.get_server`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_server) is returning `None`.  That means it can't find the server with that id.  Are you passing it as a string or an int?

Comment: server id with only numbers.

Comment: If you're using discord.py 0.16, it has to be a string.  `"1234"` instead of `1234`

Comment: yes i using 0.16 @is_member_of("1234567890")  changed different server Id still same error.

Comment: Is your bot a member of that server?

Comment: Sorry Sorry i been testing in local bot so it not worked.  i will add server ID now.

Comment: That's weird.  Try adding `print(repr(server), str(server))` right before the `raise` in the `predicate`.  If it's `None` then we know that your bot can't see your server for some reason.  If it's some falsy `Server` value (should be impossible) we can change to `if server is None:`

Comment: yes worked now. but i need a custom message for those blocked non members. were to add it ?

Comment: Subclass `CommandError` and raise that specific error when the check fails.  Then handle that error in your `on_command_error` and send the message there.  Same as your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115044/raise-custom-error-message-for

Comment: I added Subclass and `on_command_error` is that ok or i need to do any change. my code added above.