# Blacklisting bot commands with role?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi is there anyway you could simply blacklist someone from using all bot commands by role? I'm currently looking to find a way to do this for my bot which is on the Discord rewrite branch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way if probably to use a [global check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#global-checks), using the `bot.check` decorator.  The following operates based on role `name`, but you could write an equivalent version using `id`:

```
from discord.utils import get

@bot.check
async def globally_blacklist_roles(self, ctx):
    blacklist = ["BAD_ROLE_1", "BAD_ROLE_2"]  # Role names
    return not any(get(ctx.guild.roles, name=name) in ctx.author.roles for name in blacklist)
```

There are some speedups you could do here by caching the `Role` objects for the blacklisted roles, for example.

If you're using cogs, you can indicate that you want a coroutine to be a global check by giving it a special name, either `__global_check_once` or `__global_check`.  This is [documented here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#cog-changes).  It looks like `__global_check_once` is what you're looking for, but you might want to experiment.  I think the only difference is how many times it's called when you're using command groups with subcommands

```
class Blacklisted(commands.CheckFailure): pass

class YourCog:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    def __global_check_once(self, ctx):
        blacklist = ["BAD_ROLE_1", "BAD_ROLE_2"]  # Role names
        if any(get(ctx.guild.roles, name=name) in ctx.author.roles for name in blacklist):
            raise Blacklisted()
        else:
            return True

    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, Blacklisted):
            await ctx.send("You cannot use this command.")
```

Comment: Would I need to remove `@bot.check` as my bot is modular and would be creating this as a module.

Comment: @ShanJameson See my edit.  Use the global checks built into cogs as documented here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#cog-changes

Comment: I would like to add a message to this  "commands blocked" would `raise` be acceptable? if I use a ctx.send() that would throw a syntax error?

Comment: You can try making it an `async def` coroutine instead.  Really what you should do is subclass `CheckFailure`, then raise that error instead of returning `False`.  Then, write an [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) to handle that error and send the message.  See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115044/raise-custom-error-message-for)

Comment: Hi @Patrick I'm getting a bit stuck on adding a error handler to this from [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)  

I have added an answer to show you what I have tried to do see below. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @ShanJameson I've modified my answer.  `on_command_error` is an event, and cogs automatically register listeners for events when the coroutine has a name from the event reference.  (I was also missing `self` as a first argument to the check, which is important)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181910/discussion-between-shan-jameson-and-patrick-haugh).

Answer (score 0):

```
def __global_check_once(self, ctx):
    blacklist = ["Blacklisted", "Blacklist"]  # Role names
    return not any(get(ctx.guild.roles, name=name) in ctx.author.roles for name in blacklist)

async def __global_check_once_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, __global_check_once):
        await ctx.send('You cannot use that command!')
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to improve it's quality